# D3.js v4 how to reach data?

Tags: d3.js

I'm starting JavaScript and D3 for a graph visualization project, and I can't figure out how to reach the data I want. I think I'm simply unaware of some basic JS elements...

I have some nodes and links...

```
var nodes_data = [
{"id": "Node 1"},
{"id": "Node 2"},
{"id": "Node 3"},
{"id": "Node 4"},
{"id": "Node 5"}]

var links_data = [
{"source": "Node 1", "target":"Node 4"},
{"source": "Node 2", "target":"Node 1"},
{"source": "Node 1", "target":"Node 5"},
{"source": "Node 4", "target":"Node 3"},
{"source": "Node 5", "target":"Node 3"}]
```

and I simply want to highlight a link when a node is selected. My nodes are setup this way...

```
var linksRef =
svgRef.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
.selectAll("line")
.data(links_data).enter()
.append("line");

var nodesRef =
svgRef.append("g")          
    .attr("class", "nodes")
.selectAll("circle")    
.data(nodes_data).enter()
.append("circle")
    .attr("r", nodeRadius)
    .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
    .on("mouseout", mouseOut);
```

and I expected to change the link color of the hovered node this way...

```
function mouseOver(d) {
  var nodeId = d.id;
  d3.selectAll("links")
    .filter(function (d) { return d.source === nodeId })
    .style("stroke", "red");
}
```

I did try to substitute `links` there with `.links` or `link` or `.link` but those are simply shots in the dark. When I output these to console, I'm always getting empty arrays. There's cleary some JS or D3 things I didn't catch!

What's the proper way to access and filter the data in a case like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here.

`d3.selectAll("links")` will select all `links` elements in the SVG. That obviously won't work, since there is no `<links>` element in the SVG specs.

Therefore, one solution is selecting the lines:

```
d3.selectAll("line")
```

Another one, in case you have other lines in the SVG, is using the selection:

```
linksRef.selectAll("line")
```

Finally, you can just set a class...

```
var linksRef = svgRef.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links_data).enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link")
```

... and select by that class:

```
d3.selectAll(".link")
```

Comment: Great! Adding the class to the appended line seems to be the best solution, that's what I was missing :) Cheers!